# Slideshow ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, I am a beginner with jquery, so please be gentle :).Recently I found this tutorial: http://fearlessflyer.com/2010/08/how-to-create-your-own-jquery-content-slider/ which shows how to create a slideshow for beginners. I followed the tutorial exactly, and yet I am unable to get the slideshow working. Using firebug, I noticed I was getting a "**ReferenceError: theImage is not defined**" error message. Could someone please help me to understand why this error is happening.

All the css and javaScript is done in the html document and looks as follows:

```
<style>
*{padding:0; margin:0;}
ul {}
ul li {float:left; list-style:none; position:relative; }
ul li a.next {position:absolute; left:100px;}
ul li a.previous{position:absolute; left:0px;}
ul li a.startover{position:absolute; left:200px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(window).load (function() {
var theImage = $('ul li img');
var theWidth = theImage.width()
//wrap into mother div
$('ul').wrap('<div id="mother" />');                    
//assign height width and overflow hidden to mother
$('#mother').css({
    width: function() {
    return theWidth;
}, 
    height: function() {
    return theImage.height();
  }, 
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden'      
});
//get total of image sizes and set as width for ul 

var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
$('ul').css({
    width: function(){
    return totalWidth;  
}               
});     

});//doc ready


$(theImage).each(      <!-- The firebug error points to this line in code -->       
function(intIndex){             
$(this).nextAll('a')
.bind("click", function(){
    if($(this).is(".next")) {
        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
            "margin-left": (-(intIndex + 1) * theWidth)             
                }, 1000)    
        } else if($(this).is(".previous")){
        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
            "margin-left": (-(intIndex - 1) * theWidth)             
        }, 1000)    
        } else if($(this).is(".startover")){
        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
            "margin-left": (0)              
        }, 1000)
}
});//close .bind()                                   
});//close .each()

</script>

</head>
```

The error message I get in firebug points to the **$(theImage).each(** line of code as shown in the comments above. Could the solution to this error be found in using the **.noConflict()** function? if so could someone PLEASE show me how to do it, as I haven't found any helpful information on this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `theImage` in the callback for `$(window).load()`:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var theImage = $('ul li img');
```

`theImage` doesn't exist outside of that callback. You either have to define it outside of the callback:

```
var theImage;

$(window).load(function() {
    theImage = $('ul li img');
```

Or move the `$.each` into the same callback.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Blender, what you suggested makes sense (and works) although, doing what I had originally done wasn't the problem in my code. What I forgot to do was to close the second bit of code (the one that started where I got the firebug error - commented in the code above) within the doc ready closing brackets. So basically what I did wrong was:  $(window).load (function() { ... first bit of code ....}); //doc Ready ... second bit of code.  The solution was to place the second bit of code (the one giving the firebug error) before the  });//doc ready closing brackets. And it works.